# How to find every item in list who's index is two to the x power (2, 4, 8, 16 etc.)?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that has 500 items and I want to get every item that is equal to 2 to the x power to be renamed False.
The best I could come up with is this

```
items = []
x = 2
for i in range(0,9):
  for i in range(0,len(items)):
    if i+1 == 2**x:
      items[i] = False
  x += 1
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: You should use different iterator variables in both the for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
items = [123,234,100,50, 64, 25,4,22,32,45,16, 9]

x = max(items)

def maxof2(x):
    for i in range(0,9): # You can choose the range based on the max value in the list
        if 2**i < x:
            continue
        else:
            return(i)

twopowers = [2**x for x in range(0,maxof2(x))]

for i in range(len(twopowers)):
    if twopowers[i] in items:
        items[i] = False

items
```

> [123, 234, False, 50, False, False, 4, 22, 32, 45, 16, 9]